# Help understanding linux command for load test

Tags: linux

I am creating a test load for my website and I wanted to understand what this command really means?

```
('dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500 | gzip | gzip -d  > /dev/null &')
```

What I understood so far is that this is getting blocks of 100MiB of data at a time copying them to the disk and them compressing and decompressing them. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Can you specify if the brackets are part of the command?

Comment: This might stress out the CPU but really doesn't touch memory or disk. Google Linux stress tests and you'll get a lot of hits for real tools. You probably will also want to check out stress test tools specifically designed for web servers - these are very different than OS stress tools.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break the command up into the three parts

- `dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500`
- `gzip`
- `gzip -d > /dev/null &`

##### Short Version

- `dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500` reads 500 blocks of null
  characters (0x00 in ASCII), 100 MiBs of data per
  block into the pipe (`|`), essentially 'feeding' `gzip`. **Note that this doesn't write to disk.**
- `gzip` compresses the data
- `gzip -d > /dev/null` decompresses and then discards the data.

#### Longer explanation

`dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500`

- The `dd` command usually has two parameters, `if` and `of` for input
  and output file respectively. The `if` parameter here is set to
  /dev/zero, which is a special device file that returns an 'array' of
  null characters (or 0x00 in ASCII).
- You are correct about it reading blocks of 100MiB, the `bs` parameter
  facilitates this. Note that, however, it isn't writing to disk, see the next point.
- When the `of` parameter isn't present, it writes to standard output
  or `stdout` (not a file on disk, but a [stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)). Since a pipe (`|`) is used after the command, the data
  written to `stdout` gets piped (fed) into another program, here
  `gzip`
- The `count` parameter specifies the number of blocks copied.

`gzip`

- When gzip is run without specifying a file, it reads from standard input or `stdin` (here, the piped input from dd) and writes to standard output.
- By default (without the `-d` option), gzip performs compression.

`gzip -d > /dev/null`

- When gzip is run with the `-d` option, it performs decompression. Here, it reads the piped input from gzip and outputs to stdout (since no file is specified).
- The `>` character redirects streams (`stdout`,`stdin`,`stderr`) of the current command. Here it writes the `stdout` or standard output of the `gzip -d` command to device `/dev/null` which is used for discarding all written data.
- The '&' character instructs the shell to run the process in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, transcribed it means this:

```
dd if(entry device)=/dev/zero(device) (then set)bs=100M(size) (each time)count=500(times) (then send to) | (compressing)gzip (then send to) | (decompressing)gzip -d (redirect process to) > (null device)/dev/null &(don't wait)
```

**Now, the clean and detailed explanation:**

`dd`, is the command or program you are executing.

`if=`, the input device

`/dev/zero`, the device path, in this case "/dev/zero" that is a device with value 0

`bs=`, the size to specify to generate the zeros obtained from the aforementioned device /dev/zero

`100M`, 100 Megabytes of the 0 (zero) digits obtained from /dev/zero in this case.

`count=`, the number of times to repeat the process to fill something or in this case the output

`500`, 500 times, that is equal to 100M * 500 = 50000Megabytes

`|`, send the output to, in this case to gzip

`gzip`, command or program that is responsible for compressing the file in gzip format, it will compress the data comming from dd command or program.

`|`, send again to de command gzip but in this case **'gzip -d'**

`gzip -d`, gzip command or program to execute and '-d' is the option that means decompress

`> /dev/null`, redirect the process of the gzip sending it to '/dev/null'

`/dev/null`, a null device that works like a trash or empty space

`&`, means don't wait until command finish in this case, but is an basic operator of shell script, bash and others programming languages.

**Summary: You are creating a file filled with zeros(0 digits) with the 'dd' program in this case 50000 zeros, then sending it directly to the gzip program for compression, and then sending it back to gzip, but in this case to decompress it again .**

50000 zeros can change depending on the format if it is binary or decimal, this already depends on mathematics and pre-established measurements

if parentheses are a part of your command, then i parentheses mean an sub operation example: (suboperation here), another example: (command [arguments]), but generally it needs the symbol "$" to be fired, the use of these parentheses can change its meaning depending of the program in where you execute the code for example: shell script, bash and others.

Answer (score 1):

## Aside

First of all I am assuming the command is:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500 | gzip | gzip -d > /dev/null &
```

Rather than:

```
('dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500 | gzip | gzip -d > /dev/null &')
```

The parentheses would be fairly harmless, instructing the shell to execute the pipeline in a subshell, but the single quotes would cause a problem. They would instruct the shell to treat the whole pipeline as a single parameter, which the shell would then attempt to execute as the command name. The shell will (more than likely) fail to find a command with the name `('dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500 | gzip | gzip -d > /dev/null &')` in its path, and tell you so:

```
-bash: dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=500 | gzip | gzip -d > /dev/null &: No such file or directory
```

## Now to answer the question

The `dd` command copies the standard input, or the file specified with `if=`, to the standard output, or the file specified with `of=`. This load test command uses `/dev/zero` for the input. `/dev/zero` is special pseudo-device file handled by the kernel. When read from, the file produces an endless stream of null characters.

The output of the `dd` command (500 blocks at 100M per block of nothing but null characters) is then passed via the pipe metacharacter `|` to the `gzip` command, which compresses the data on the fly and passes it via another pipe `|` to `gzip -d`, which decompresses the data on the fly. The `>` is a shell redirect operator that instructs the shell to write the output of the last command in the pipeline to the specified file, in this case `/dev/null`. Nothing is actually written, because `/dev/null` is another special pseudo-device file handled by the kernel, and all write operations to this file are silently dropped.

You mentioned the data being copied to disk. Because `/dev/null` is a special "black hole" file, and the other commands read and write from standard input and standard output, nothing is written to any disk, unless the system is swapping memory to disk.

The `&` metacharacter instructs the shell to run the pipeline in the background.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention first command get 50G symbols from device `/dev/zero` and send them to STDOUT, on the same time `gzip` get from STDIN this stream, compress it and send it to STDOUT and on the same time `gzip -d` get the compressed stream from STDIN and decompress it sending the output to the `dev/null` (black hole). And put all this in background

But with small modifications the command can provide bigger load, because compressing zeroes is trivial process :)

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=100M count=500 | gzip -9 | gzip -d > /dev/null &
```

getting random number will make compression more "heavy". Also increasing the level of compression will increase the load of the machine.

Comment: I'm not sure what will eat more CPU – random generation or gzip!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, each of them with have own part of the load :) (IMHO `gzip` will have bigger when deal with random data and higher level of compression)

Comment: I'll need to benchmark that (`perf record -a sh -c 'dd if=/dev/random bs=100M count=500 | gzip -9 | gzip -d > /dev/null'; perf report`) later on. (It's really not a great benchmark, it runs with a smaller amount of data on my shell than on `sh`.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, in busybox,, Windows, bs=1M,count 50 i get: 0,39s /dev/zero, 25s /dev/random+ `-9`